# ¿Cómo solucionar esta violación de segmento?

Tags: c, hilos

Quiero realizar un fork de **x** hilos hasta cierto valor **y**. Logro hacer que se me compile el programa, pero al ejecutarlo me muestra el mensaje:

> Violación de segmento (`core' generado)

Éste es el código fuente de mi programa:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<unistd.h>


void *runner(void *arg)
{
pid_t a;
int x,y;
int z=0;

printf("el hilo empieza a ejecutarse.......\n");
printf("ingrese una cantidad x:");
scanf("%d",&x);
printf("ingrese la cantidad de veces que se ejecutará la acción y:");
scanf("%d",&y);

if((a=fork())==0){

while(z<=y && y!=0)
{
printf("soy thread n°%d del tiempo:%d",x,z);
z++;
}
 }
return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
pthread_t piola; //identificación del thread
int value = atoi(argv[1]);

if(0 != pthread_create(&piola,NULL,runner, &value));
return -1;

pthread_join(piola,NULL);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema que estás sufriendo se origina en la siguiente línea:

```
int value = atoi(argv[1]);
```

Estás asumiendo que existe ese parámetro y, sin embargo, `argv[1]` podría no está definido si no pasas un primer parámetro al ejecutable, siendo un valor indefinido (en el mejor de los casos es cero, dando un puntero a `NULL`).

Si compilas con información de depuración:

```
gcc -pthread -g -o ejemplo ejemplo.c
```

Y luego le pasas `valgrind`:

```
$ valgrind ./ejemplo 
==23680== Command: ./ejemplo
==23680== 
==23680== Invalid read of size 1
==23680==    at 0x50A01B0: ____strtol_l_internal (strtol_l.c:292)
==23680==    by 0x509B68F: atoi (atoi.c:27)
==23680==    by 0x108971: main (ejemplo.c:34)
==23680==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==23680== 
==23680== 
==23680== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==23680==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==23680==    at 0x50A01B0: ____strtol_l_internal (strtol_l.c:292)
==23680==    by 0x509B68F: atoi (atoi.c:27)
==23680==    by 0x108971: main (ejemplo.c:34)
==23680== 
==23680== HEAP SUMMARY:
==23680==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23680==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
Violación de segmento (`core' generado)
```

Lo más relevante de la salida es el siguiente mensaje:

```
==23680==    by 0x108971: main (ejemplo.c:34)
==23680==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Donde te dice que en la línea 34 (la que te indico) se está accediendo a un puntero `NULL` (`0x0`).

Lo correcto sería comprobar previamente si existe el número suficiente de parámetros y mostrar un mensaje de error y/o ayuda de la siguiente manera:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  pthread_t piola; //identificación del thread
  int value;
  if (argc < 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Uso: %s <numero>\n", argv[0]);
    return -1;
  }
  value = atoi(argv[1]);

  if(0 != pthread_create(&piola, NULL, runner, &value)) {
    return -1;
  }

  pthread_join(piola, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

---

Aún así `valgrind` informa de otras fugas de memoria:

```
$ valgrind ./ejemplo 1
==24892== Command: ./ejemplo 1
==24892== 
el hilo empieza a ejecutarse.......
el hilo empieza a ejecutarse.......
ingrese una cantidad x: (...)
==24892== 
==24892== HEAP SUMMARY:
==24892==     in use at exit: 272 bytes in 1 blocks
==24892==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 2 frees, 2,320 bytes allocated
```

Probablemente sea debido a que estás usando `fork()` dentro de un hilo, cuando lo normal es crear procesos y que cada proceso, a su vez, genere varios hilos. El analizador `valgrind` analiza el uso de memoria al finalizar cada proceso, por lo que detecta que existe una hebra que aún tiene recursos reservados.

Si modifico tu código de la siguiente manera:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void *runner(void *arg)
{
  pid_t a;
  int z = 0;

  printf("El hilo empieza a ejecutarse.\n");

  if ((a = fork()) == 0) {
    while (z <= *(int *)arg) {
      printf("Soy hijo %d, iteración: %d\n", a, z);
      z++;
    }
  } else {
    printf("Soy padre, parámetro: %d\n", *(int *)arg);
    wait(&a);
    printf("El hijo salió con estado %d\n", a);
  }
  pthread_exit((void *)pthread_self());
  return NULL;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  pthread_t piola; //identificación del thread
  int value;

  if (argc < 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Uso: %s <numero>\n", argv[0]);
    return -1;
  }
  value = atoi(argv[1]);

  if (pthread_create(&piola, NULL, runner, &value)) {
    return -1;
  }

  pthread_join(piola, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

Al ejecutar `valgrind` ahora obtenemos:

```
$ gcc --pedantic -Wall -pthread -g -o ejemplo ejemplo.c && valgrind ./ejemplo 3
==4763== Command: ./ejemplo 3
==4763== 
El hilo empieza a ejecutarse.
Soy padre, parámetro: 3
Soy hijo 0, iteración: 0
Soy hijo 0, iteración: 1
Soy hijo 0, iteración: 2
Soy hijo 0, iteración: 3
==4766== 
==4766== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4766==     in use at exit: 272 bytes in 1 blocks
==4766==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 6 frees, 2,990 bytes allocated
El hijo salió con estado 0
==4763== 
==4763== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4763==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4763==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 7 frees, 2,990 bytes allocated
```

Ahora `valgrind` se queja al salir del primer proceso (por los recursos de la hebra que aún no han sido liberados) y al finalizar el padre da por bueno el uso de memoria.

Comment: entiendo, mi problema es que soy nuevo con el tema de los threads y apenas supe como seria para crearlos

Comment: el valgrind no detecta el error que a ti te ha dado, sin embargo al ejecutar, en lugar de pedirme los valores x e y, me salta directamente al mensaje de error planteado en el main del thread "Uso: %s <numero>\n" ```int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  pthread_t piola; //identificación del thread
  int value;
  if (argc < 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Uso: %s <numero>\n", argv[0]);
    return -1;
  }
  value = atoi(argv[1]);

  if(0 != pthread_create(&piola, NULL, runner, &value)) {
    return -1;
  }

  pthread_join(piola, NULL);

  return 0;
}```

Comment: Mira el `if`, lo tienes mal por poner un punto y coma al final (se entiende que ahí termina el `if`). En mi respuesta lo corregí. Deberías acostumbrarte a usar llaves SIEMPRE, aunque sea una única instrucción lo que hay en el `if` o el `else`, te evitará muchos quebraderos de cabeza.

Comment: Por cierto, lo normal es crear múltiples procesos con `fork` y luego varias hebras por cada proceso. De ese modo siempre harás el `pthread_join` de las hebras creadas antes de terminar cada proceso.